# Transfer Learning and Unknown Object Identification

Tags: image-classification, transfer-learning

Is it a good idea to use pre-trained weights of say VGG19 (or other) model for a classification problem for a completely a new class of object altogether?

Whole idea is, I'm working on a binary image classification problem and I want to use transfer learning. I have used VGG19 model and its pre-trained weights. Instead of using the last layer of VGG19, I have used the last fully connected(FC) layer having size [-1, 4096] and plugged few of my FC layers with it.

My questions are:

1. VGG19 is not trained for that particular class, is it still ok to use pre-trained weights or should I use this or other architecture only?
2. If it's ok to use pre-trained weights, should I incrementally trained these VGG19 weights or just trained my newly connected layers?

Thanks.

Comment: It is true that  VGG19 is not trained for your class, but it is still worth to evaluate it as it is. Likely it won't perform well, depending how distinct your objects are compared to VGG19 trained objects. If so distinct, likely you need to re-train. But not from scratch. That is the whole point of transfer learning. You better use the pre-trained weights and start loosing up last layers (of course you need to add last layer matching number of your classes) one at a time to re-train.

Comment: Thanks, so I should try with pre-trained weights.